# Why is it not saving to variable?

Tags: python

This SaveMEM function I wrote doesn't work, why?
All variable values have been tested, and im pertty sure every thing else *should* work, so why does it not?

```
def SaveMeM(Target, Value):
    if Target == '1':
        Reg1 = Value
    if Target == '2':
        Reg2 = Value
    if Target == '3':
        Reg3 = Value
    if Target == '4':
        Reg4 = Value
    if Target == '5':
        Reg5 = Value
    if Target == '6':
        Reg6 = Value
    if Target == '7':
        Reg7 = Value
    if Target == '8':
        Reg8 = Value
    if Target == 'RAM' :
        RAM.append(Value)
    if Target == 'ALL':
        SaveMeM('Reg1', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg2', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg3', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg4', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg5', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg6', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg7', Value)
        SaveMeM('Reg8', Value)
        SaveMeM('RAM', Value)
```

Comment: You pass `'Reg1'` as function argument, but you test `Target == '1'`

Comment: What is it supposed to do? How are you calling this function? Your last `if` statement tests for `'ALL'` but i dont see `'ALL'` ever being passed in? In your `'ALL'` part you call it by passing in `'Reg1'` as the `Target` but then test this against `1`. `'Reg1'` is not equal to `'1'`. You dont return anything from this function. Back to the `'ALL'` part. the `Value` youre passing to the function is the same value in every function call

Comment: Also 'does not work' is not an accurate or helpful description of any problem if youre looking for help to debug it. You need to explain what youre trying to do, what the output should be, and what the issue is. Its always good to have a read through here - https://stackoverflow.com/help - to get an idea of how to ask questions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the final if block you are using "Reg1" ,"Reg2".... instead of "1","2",...

And Target is compared with "1","2","3",...... So All cases will fail except "RAM".

SO change final IF block as this

```
if Target == 'ALL':
        SaveMeM('1', Value)
        SaveMeM('2', Value)
        SaveMeM('3', Value)
        SaveMeM('4', Value)
        SaveMeM('5', Value)
        SaveMeM('6', Value)
        SaveMeM('7', Value)
        SaveMeM('8', Value)
        SaveMeM('RAM', Value)
```